# Additional paypal fee on Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, we are trying to add an additional cost to the order when is purchased via Paypal payment gateway.

We did it changing the price that is sent to Paypal this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'addition_pay');

function addition_pay($paypal_args){
        $new_value=$paypal_args['amount_1']+10;
        $paypal_args['amount_1']=$new_value;
        return $paypal_args;
}
```

It works, but the problem is after the payment process, this additional cost is not reflected in Orders and email notifications.

Is this can be solved in some way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better add a fee based on payment gateway (here Paypal for you), like in the following:

```
// Add a fee of 10.00 when Paypal is chosen
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_paypal_additional_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_paypal_additional_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' ) == 'paypal' )
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Paypal fee', 'woocommerce' ), 10.00 );
}

// Add the information on checkout paypal text gateways section
add_filter('woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'custom_paypal_gateway_text', 20, 2 );
function custom_paypal_gateway_text( $html, $gateway_id ) {
    if( $gateway_id == 'paypal' )
        $html .= ' <small class="paypal-fee">(+ '.wc_price(10.00).')</small>';

    return $html;
}

// Enable ajax update checkout event when choosing a gateway to refresh the fee
add_action('wp_footer', 'payment_gateways_update_checkout_event' );
function payment_gateways_update_checkout_event() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                var t = { updateTimer: !1,  dirtyInput: !1,
                    reset_update_checkout_timer: function() {
                        clearTimeout(t.updateTimer)
                    },  trigger_update_checkout: function() {
                        t.reset_update_checkout_timer(), t.dirtyInput = !1,
                        $(document.body).trigger("update_checkout")
                    }
                };
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout')
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and work.

[image]