# Woocommerce, add fee when user selects an option in checkout

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a payment gateway (bank) which has a select option of installment
When user choose an option it should update checkout total with a fee (cart total * 0.12 *installments/12)

```
<p class="form-row woocommerce-validated">
        <label for="piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis">Επιλογή Δόσεων <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <select id="piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis" name="piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis" class="input-select wc-credit-card-form-card-doseis">
                    <option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select>         
    </p>
```

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475960/additional-paypal-fee-on-woocommerce-checkout-page/49478860#4947886)

Comment: But how can i get the #piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis value
When user change it ( because the added fee must be calculated based to that )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a fee (generally) LoicTheAztec's answer is working.
But in order to get the value of installments ( "piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis")

you need to add in code ( by my unknowledge I was trying $_POST['piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis'] which is wrong )
in theme's function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_paypal_additional_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_paypal_additional_fee( $cart ) {
            if ( isset($_POST['post_data'])) {
                parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
            } else {
                 $post_data = $_POST; // fallback for final checkout (non-ajax)
            }
            if (isset($post_data['piraeusbank_gateway-card-doseis'])) {
...
```

Comment: Can you explain your code in more detail on where do we put this code