# Rounding WooCommerce total amount for PayPal

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, rounding, rounding-error

In a shop with sometimes absurd price display misbehaviour, I have solved the problem by rounding with this function:

```
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', function ( $price ) {
$decimals = round( $price - floor( $price ), 2 );
return ( $decimals == 0.01 || $decimals == 0.99 ) ? round( $price ) : $price;
} );
```

It works...so I thought. I was only half right...it works in the shop and in the front- and backend and on the invoices...but PayPal seems to receive the wrong unrounded amount.

I've been searching for a filter similar to raw_woocommerce_price, something like raw_paypal_price, but couldn't find anything. If there was one I could round the price before PayPal receives the (wrong) amount.

Does someone know of such a filter, or what else to use? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use [`woocommerce_paypal_args` hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/gateways/paypal/includes/class-wc-gateway-paypal-request.php#L202)… See some [related threads using `woocommerce_paypal_args` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_paypal_args)

Comment: Thanks! Looks good...especially this one here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475960/additional-paypal-fee-on-woocommerce-checkout-page