# woocommerce_paypal_args ... possible Arguments

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, hook-woocommerce

I would like to round the total that is handed over to PayPal. For that I think I should use something like

```
add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'round_total_pp');

function round_total_pp($paypal_args){
        $new_total=round($paypal_args['amount_1']);
        $paypal_args['amount_1']=$new_total;
        return $paypal_args;
}
```

that I found here: [Additional paypal fee on Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475960/additional-paypal-fee-on-woocommerce-checkout-page)

But I am unsure about the right argument. Is it really "amount_1"?

Maybe there is a list of possible arguments, but I haven't found it yet...

Comment: Just tried the above code with amount_1, but the PP amount was not being rounded. So I suppose it's the wrong argument name.

Comment: This page here tells me that amount_1 is indeed the right argument name: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/